# Load/store register results in different value than memory viewer

Tags: arm, qemu, xilinx, bare-metal, zynq

I'm working on a program that runs under Xilinx's QEMU builds. This question is tagged [zynq](/questions/tagged/zynq), but I'm actually targeting a Zynq MP in QEMU, specifically the Cortex-R5.

My background is in microcontrollers and Cortex-M, so this is a big jump and there are a lot of features (MPU, AXI, extra caches) that I'm not accustomed to. I'm writing a driver that is accessing peripheral registers in one of the hard peripherals (in the low power domain). I've written a function, `reginsert` to simplify accessing bits in these registers.

```
void reginsert(uint32_t base, uint32_t offset,
               uint32_t mask, uint32_t data)
{
    uint32_t volatile * reg = (uint32_t volatile *)(base + offset);
    uint32_t regdata;
    /* This section actually happens in a critical section for atomicity, 
     * but I've trimmed that out for brevity */
    regdata = *reg;
    *reg = (regdata & ~mask) | data;
    /* End of critical section */
}
```

Not a very exciting function at all. To me, it's also straightforward.

I call the function like so:

```
/* Magic number provided by Xilinx, I don't actually plan to keep it as such a
 * magical number, but for now while trying things to debug. */
reginsert(XPAR_PSU_UART_0_BASEADDR, XUARTPS_CR_OFFSET, 0x3C, 0);
```

Additional information:

```
#define XPART_PSU_UART_0_BASEADDR 0xFF000000
#define XUARTPS_CR_OFFSET         0x00000000
```

In stepping through the code, I find that this function correctly calculates the address for the register as `0xFF000000`, and I can see this within the Xilinx SDK debugger (gdb based) when viewing the value for `reg`. I can also see, stepping through the assembly that the register `r3` is loaded with the proper address.

When execution reaches:

```
regdata = *reg;
```

The disassembly has:

```
ldr r3, [r3]
```

And I get `0x00000000` in `r3`. If I use the memory view, I can see that `0xFF000000` has a value of `0x00000114`. If I look in the variable view, I can see that `*reg` has the same value (`0x00000114`). If I step to the line where the local copy is masked and then written back, I end up at the instruction:

```
str r2, [r3]   ; r3 has been reloaded with the register address,
               ; and r2 contains the read-modify-write data.
```

Stepping past this, I see that the value of `0x00000000` (though not the correct value) should have been written, but the value does not actually change (via memory or variable view). In either of these views, I can manually change the value and it writes correctly.

I don't know how thoroughly the bus architecture of the Zynq MP is being emulated in this build of QEMU, but the silicon has separate memory ports for debug access and processor access, and does not access memory through the CPU, so there is a possibility for things to be mapped differently. However, the Xilinx demo code does appropriately perform the same actions.

So, a summary of what I've tried:

1. Verify disassembly should load/store from register location.
2. Step through instructions to verify CPU registers have the correct value to access peripheral register.
3. Accessed memory and variable directly via debugger.
4. Verify with Xilinx code that QEMU emulates peripheral.
5. Checked MPU settings (the region is set to non-shared and no restrictions on access)

I don't know what else I should try, and I'm basically stumped. It appears that QEMU, at least through the gdb interface, properly simulates the peripheral register, so I would think it would be fairly straightforward for the CPU to read/write. I appreciate any help, pointers, tips, etc. There's a lot going on that is new to me, including using QEMU as a development platform.

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual question to answer is? "QEMU's GDB stub is a bit wonky with emulated peripheral registers" isn't a question as such, and were it to be formed into one, I'm not entirely sure what the answer would be other than "because QEMU".

Comment: @Notlikethat The question is really "what else is there to check that could cause this difference between execution of the instruction, and the gdb stub" and the answer may very well be "nothing, QEMU's peripheral emulation is wonky". I'm not familiar enough with QEMU to know if it's common to see behaviors like this where perhaps a peripheral has its high level functions emulated, but not have all the configuration registers implemented.

Comment: @Notlikethat, so it actually seemed to be my own foolishness, possibly with some wonkiness. It seems that the issue went away when I disable the watchpoint I had set on that memory location. Do you think this is a case where I should delete the question?

Comment: Well, if setting a watchpoint on a peripheral address makes QEMU's debugger act weirdly, that seems like the kind of thing someone else might run into in future - you've got a clear problem description here, so even if the question to frame it as _is_ simply "what's going on here and can I do anything about it?", the fact that you've now got something to directly answer it with [has value](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: No reason to expect a debugger to work, runtime vs single step.  Definitely no reason to expect QEMU works in this way.  No reason to expect that QEMU and the silicon match.  There are other ways to debug without a debugger and single stepping that may just work.  If this is just a case of why doesnt QEMU work, well dig into the QEMU sources, faster and easier to just try some other form of debugging that doesnt break the pipe or flow of code or muck with timing, etc.